# Understanding how to optimize a query via the Postgres/rails explain data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following query:

```
c = Invite.where(:invite_method => 'email', :email => email, :created_at => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).count
```

This query is taking some time as the table has 1m+ records. Here is the query output:

```
> invites_sent_today = Invite.where(:invite_method => 'email', :email => email, :created_at => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day).exp 

Invite Load (62.3ms)  SELECT "invites".* FROM "invites" WHERE "invites"."invite_method" = 'email' AND "invites"."email" = 'santa@site.com' AND ("invites"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-01-20 00:00:00.000000' AND '2013-01-20 23:59:59.999999')

EXPLAIN (2.2ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT "invites".* FROM "invites" WHERE "invites"."invite_method" = 'email' AND "invites"."email" = 'santa@site.com' AND ("invites"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-01-20 00:00:00.000000' AND '2013-01-20 23:59:59.999999')

=> EXPLAIN for:

SELECT \"invites\".*
  FROM \"invites\"
 WHERE \"invites\".\"invite_method\" = 'email' 
   AND \"invites\".\"email\" = 'santa@site.com'
   AND (\"invites\".\"created_at\"
    BETWEEN '2013-01-2000:00:00.000000'                                                             
       AND'2013-01-20 23:59:59.999999'
      ;

QUERY PLAN\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n 
Index Scan using index_invites_on_created_at on invites  (cost=0.00..17998.11 rows=2 width=129)\n   
Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2013-01-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at <= '2013-01-20 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone))\n   
Filter: (((invite_method)::text = 'email'::text) AND ((email)::text = 'santa@site.com'::text))\n(3 rows)\n"
```

Any suggestions on how to possibly improve this query performance? Thanks

Comment: Composite or partial index can speed up this particular query.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko thanks, could you share an example?

Comment: Example: `CREATE INDEX zzzzz ON invites (email) WHERE invite_method = 'email'` BTW: the way to check the queryplan is to run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query statement`, and look at the differences between observed and expected.

Comment: Do you always query for last 24h ? Yes -> create extra table and truncate it at the end of the day, queries  will be extra fast. If cardinality on email is better create index on email

Comment: @iddqd Maybe a partial index for the last day would be better? And recreate the index at the end of the day.

Comment: Love the partial index idea. Something where invite.created_at is 3 days or earlier. Do you have to recreate that manually. Postgres can't figure that out?

Comment: @AnApprentice If you want a partial index on data for the last day (or 3 days or ...) you must recreate the index, because the the day that is "last day" changes constantly. If you want a partial index on something like `"invite_method" = 'email'` - you do not need to recreate it.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko can postgres dynamically handle the condition, last 3 days?

Comment: @AnApprentice See my previous comment. The filter condition is set when the partial index is created. The only way to change it - recreate an index.

Comment: @AnApprentice Maybe a composite index on `(created_at, invite_method)` will be better?

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko I'm learning here. Why a composite index?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23063/discussion-between-igor-romanchenko-and-anapprentice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Igor, try a composite index :

```
CREATE INDEX index_invites_email_created_at on invites(email,created_at);
```