# Why are our Rails database queries slow in spite of Heroku database caching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rails-activerecord

We previously used the Heroku Basic database, but found that operations on our site involving heavy database queries were very slow. We upgraded to the Heroku Crane database 3 days ago in hopes that it would help with the problem. However, the queries seem just as slow. Even running the same operation twice in a row seems slow, while I would expect it to be fast due to the caching.

Our database size is only 15.4MB, while the Crane database we are using provides 400MB of cache. In theory, it seems like the entire database could be cached, thus providing very fast query processing. Should this be the case? How can we go about solving or troubleshooting the problem? Also, is the cache disk block-based, or is it query based (i.e., do we have to run the exact same query twice in order to benefit from the caching?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

FYI I work on the Heroku Postgres team.

In general, Postgres will cache the underlying table data that it pulls from disk, so you will have to operate on it at least once to get it loaded into memory. However, if you are doing complicated queries, caching the data won't get you that much and sometimes Rails can not delegate enough of the work to the db, leaving your application CPU bound and your db underutilized.

I would dig into optimizing your queries and indexes to let Postgres work its magic a little better. You can start by running `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to figure out what part of your query is taking a long time.

Good resources for optimizing your db usage: http://www.freebsddiary.org/postgresql-analyze.php and http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

An example of using EXPLAIN in rails: [Understanding how to optimize a query via the Postgres/rails explain data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428547/understanding-how-to-optimize-a-query-via-the-postgres-rails-explain-data)

Answer (score 0):

with that small of a database, you should not see any performance issues. 
I would profile the app and tease out the slow parts, as I recommend here: 
[Rails Performance Tuning for Production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022554/rails-performance-tuning-for-production/8420679#8420679)